# Calculate two values systematic from the same column in a precedure (mysql)

Tags: mysql

I have 2 columns that I want to multiply "speed" and "distance" points for each set thay appeare

The table:

**--- type --- | --- points ---**
....speed....|.......25........
....junk.......|.........1........
..distance..|......120........
....speed....|.......19........
....junk.......|.........1........
..distance..|......102........
....speed....|.......15........
....junk.......|.........1........
..distance..|.......99........
...

speed(25) * distance(120) save value
speed(19) * distance(102) save value
speed(15) * distance(99) save value

And in the end get the SUM(value)

I want to do something like this:(I know its so wrong but anyway you know what I mean...)

```
SET value = (SELECT SUM(t.v)
             FROM(
                 ((SELECT (points) s FROM UserData WHERE type = 'speed')
                 *
                 (SELECT (points) d FROM UserData WHERE type = 'distance'))
                 v
             ) t);
```

Comment: Can you provide your table structure fully? By what means does speed and distance are related? Assuming you're saying it as "set", you mean the 1st and 2nd row, then 3rd and 4th row, so on... ?

Comment: Yes that is what I meant. The real table have some basic structure.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, "its so wrong", but assuming the data is reliably in the order you've shown, this might work ....

```
SET @i := 0;
SET @part := 0;
SET @running := 0;

SELECT IF(@i=0, @part := `points`, @part := @part * `points`) AS `current_partial`
   , IF(@i=1, @running := @running + @part , @running) AS `incremental_running`  
   , @i := IF(@i=1,0,1) AS `stage`
FROM some_ridiculous_table
;

SELECT @running;
```